# How to load Preference file in Libgdx asynchronously using Asset manager?

Tags: libgdx

The Preference and AssetManager documentations don't mention this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with libGDX, but it appears that Preferences should not be treated as assets.

Comment: Exactly, you don't load them with the asset manager. If you are having performance issues when loading preference synchronously, then you must be misusing them. They are not meant to save complex states.